# Проверить соседние элементы массива

Tags: javascript

помогите советом, как найти соседние элементы по горизонтали и вертикали.
К примеру:
findClaster(8, 3) равно 2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно что бы все соседние двойки заменились на 8, и так дальше по цепочке.
Пока что не получается добиться нужного результата, почему то пропускает некоторые двойки.

```js
var arrayGrid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 0],
    [4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 4, 5],
    [0, 5, 1, 0, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 5],
    [3, 0, 3, 0, 5, 5, 5, 1, 4, 2],
    [4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3],
    [0, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2],
    [0, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4],
    [2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 0],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 0, 2, 1]
]
var foundClaster = arrayGrid;

function findClaster(y, x) {
       if (arrayGrid[y][x - 1] == 2) {
    foundClaster[y][x - 1] = 8;
    findClaster(y, x - 1)
}
if (arrayGrid[y][x + 1] == 2) {
    foundClaster[y][x + 1] = 8;
    findClaster(y, x + 1)
}
if (arrayGrid[y - 1][x] == 2) {
    foundClaster[y - 1][x] = 8;
    findClaster(y - 1, x)
}
if (arrayGrid.length - 1 >= y + 1) {
    if (arrayGrid[y + 1][x] == 2) {
        foundClaster[y + 1][x] = 8;
        findClaster(y + 1, x)
    }
}
}

findClaster(8, 3);
foundClaster[8][3] = 8;

console.log(foundClaster)
```

з.ы. Задача решена.

Comment: у тебя только три направления проверяется: лево, право, верх, а надо еще и низ.

Comment: Если проверяю, бьет ошибку, так как y + 1 == 9, такого подмассива нет

Comment: Так и проверь - выходит за границы или нет :-)

Comment: проверил, не помогло :(

Comment: и еще у тебя опечатка: `foundClaster[y - 1][x] == 8;`

Comment: @Grundy, код ТС, потенциально, может забить стек?

Comment: @Grundy большое спасибо, именно в этом и была проблема, проверка вниз и опечатка :)

Comment: @Дмытрык, нужно сильно постараться, чтобы забить