# Заменить часть многомерного массива

Tags: javascript

Дано массив, нужно заменить окруженные значения
пример на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все значения ниже красной линии должны быть 6, все что имеет контакт через соседние позиции с верхом должно остаться не тронутым.
Прошу хотя бы пнуть в какую сторону смотреть, даже примерно не могу сообразить как такое реализовать.

```js
var arrayGrid = [
    [5, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 5, 3, 5],
    [4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
    [2, 3, 5, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2],
    [2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5],
    [3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 6, 2, 2],
    [5, 3, 1, 0, 5, 2, 6, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1],
    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2, 3],
    [6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4],
    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 2, 6],
    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 6, 2],
    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
    [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
]

var line = []


function findClear(y, x) {
    if (x >= 10) {
        return line;
    }
    if (arrayGrid[y - 1][x + 1] == 6) {
        line.push(y - 1)
        findClear(y - 1, x + 1)
    } else if (arrayGrid[y][x + 1] == 6) {
        line.push(y)
        findClear(y, x + 1)
    } else if (arrayGrid[y + 1][x + 1] == 6) {
        line.push(y + 1)
        findClear(y + 1, x + 1)
    }

}

findClear(7, 0)
console.log(line)
if(line.length < 10){
    line = [];
    findClearOpposite(9, 10)
}
function findClearOpposite(y, x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return line;
    }
    if (arrayGrid[y - 1][x - 1] == 6) {
        line.push(y - 1)
        findClearOpposite(y - 1, x - 1)
    } else if (arrayGrid[y][x - 1] == 6) {
        line.push(y)
        findClearOpposite(y, x - 1)
    } else if (arrayGrid[y + 1][x - 1] == 6) {
        line.push(y + 1)
        findClearOpposite(y + 1, x - 1)
    }

}
console.log(line)
```

Задача решена простым способом если не получилось слева направо, то пробуем справа налево.
Большое спасибо за идеи и советы.

Comment: каким образом формируется красная линия?

Comment: Должна быть непрерывная связь 6 от одной стороны массива до другой, на рисунке есть 6 выше красной линии, но эта цепочка не выходит к краю массива

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ловите решение:

```
var array =
    [
        [5, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 5, 3, 5],
        [4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
        [2, 3, 5, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2],
        [2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5],
        [3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 6, 2, 2],
        [5, 3, 1, 0, 5, 2, 6, 2, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2, 3],
        [6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 2, 6],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 6, 2],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
    ],
    line = [7,7,6,6,7,8,9,10,10,9];

for(var y = 0; y < array.length; y++)
{
    for(var x = 0; x < array[y].length; x++)
    {
        if(y > line[x])
            array[y][x] = 6
    }
}

console.log(array);
```

---

**Добавлено спустя 12 часов:**

Поскольку мне из нижеследующего общения стали известны ваши намерения и название игры, то полный код вашей игры на чистом JavaScript с подробным объяснением вы найдёте по ссылкам:

1. [Код вашей игры на чистом JavaScript с подробным объяснением](http://rembound.com/articles/bubble-shooter-game-tutorial-with-html5-and-javascript)
2. [Код вашей игры «Bubble-Shooter-HTML5» на Github](https://github.com/rembound/Bubble-Shooter-HTML5)

Comment: А как автоматически формировать массив line? Если в ручную, то я просто могу заменить то что нужно.

Comment: Автоматически? Используйте свои предыдущие наработки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828884/Проверить-соседние-элементы-массива?

Comment: @VladVityuk, чтобы автоматически создать массив line вам нужно перебрать ваш массив.Для этого вы в нём, как и [в своей предыдущей наработке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/828884/) ищете значения, на основе равных соседних чисел. Индекс в массиве line соответствует х (положению по горизонтали), а значения в нём соответствуют у (положению по вертикали).

Comment: Пробую, не получается :(

Comment: @VladVityuk, ваша картинка и массив не соответствуют друг другу. Мне не понятно что там надо искать. С игрой я тоже не знаком. Как она называется? И объясните на основе чего искать эту линию. Будет полезным также, если вы напишете тут как вы эту линию пытались искать (т.е. ваш код).

Comment: Картинка просто для наглядности, Bubbles classic, цепочка из самых верхних шестёрок которой можно соединить два края массива, код примера добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Почему код огромный?

Comment: @Duoxx, об этом нужно спросить разработчиков stackoverflow. Я его таким не делал. Это как-то связано с выполняемостью кода. Пришлось её убрать.

Comment: @VladVityuk, добавил для вас в ответ ссылки на полный код вашей игры на чистом JavaScript с подробным объяснением.

Comment: Уже находил, разобраться не получилось, просто копировать не хочется.